# Javascript only works with iframe reload

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have iframe and i have custom javascript for content of iframe. when iframe loaded for first time my custom javascript has no effect but when i right click on iframe and click reload this frame it loading my javascript and working fine.

can any one tell me how can my javascript works at first time.

iframe src is not from same domain.

Comment: impossible to tell why. Either cache or error.

Comment: @Danish, by custom JavaScript, do you mean inline code in the page loading in IFrame, or do you have separate file referenced using `<script>` tag ?

Comment: @epascarello no error in console though.

Comment: @CharmisVarghese i have a separate file referenced using <script>

Comment: Can you verify using browser's network tab(in debugging/dev tools) or using Fiddler that your referenced file is downloading from server (for the first time) ?

Comment: @CharmisVarghese yes its loading for first time

Comment: Can you add `console.log` or `alert` to the beginning of the file (not inside any function) ?

Comment: @CharmisVarghese ok the file is loading when i press reload iframe in browser. how can i load it earlier ?

Comment: @DanishJamshed, did you mean that your js file is loading only on reload ? Slightly confused with your earlier comment "_yes its loading for first time_"

Comment: when i checked this with alert i saw the alert is not coming for first time but in network its showing me the file is loaded. i am confused here as well. not sure whats going on